# HTML input field jumps

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 2 text fields, user and password. When I enter the password, it jumps to the first one. I have no idea why that is happening. I couldn't find why it is jumping. How do I change it so the password form doesn't jump? Here is the code:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'database.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){

echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user'];

?>

<form name="logout" method="post" action="logout.php">

<input type="submit" name="logout" id="logout" value="Logout">

</form>

<br /><form name="news" method="post" action="news.php">

 <input type="submit" name="news" id="news" value="News">

</form>

<?php

}

elseif(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){

echo"Welcome ".$_SESSION['admin'];

echo"<br><br>You are logged in as an Admin";

?>

<form name="logout" method="post" action="logout.php">

<input type="submit" name="logout" id="logout" value="Logout">

</form>



</form>

<?php

}else{

?>

<form name="login_form" method="post" action="login2.php">

 <label>

 <input name="user" type="text" id="user">ID<br />

 <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass">Password<br />

 </label>

 <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" action="index.php" value="Login">

 </label>

 </p>

</form>

<form name="Register" method="post" action="reg.php">

 <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register">

</form><br />

<form name="news" method="post" action="news.php">

 <input type="submit" name="news" id="news" value="News">

</form>

<?php

 }

 ?>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. On which browser(s) did you observe it? Does it still happen if you test with a page containing the login form alone? (There are many things to fix in the code, but I don’t see any of them as causing the issue.) – Sorry, now I see that the problem is that if you *first* click on the password field (somewhat oddly), then Firefox focuses on the user name field (due to wrong `label` markup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
    <label>

     <input name="user" type="text" id="user">ID<br />

     <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass">Password<br />

 </label>
```

Should be this:

```
<input name="user" type="text" id="user">
<label for="user">ID</label><br />
<input name="pass" type="password" id="pass">
<label for="pass">Password</label><br />
```

Answer (score 3):

You have both of the inputs wrapped in one label.  The browser is getting confused and it thinks that that entire content is a label for the first input (that's how labels work, apparently).  You should only use `<label>` to wrap text for input.

Comment: Plus he has two fields with the same name and id.

Comment: Correct solution, however, I like to wrap `label`'s around the 1 (one) input, as fiddling with unnecessary ID's it just to much work for poor ol' me (and it's valid use I might add). But indeed, never around more then 1.

Comment: @Wrikken I do that too.  I didn't mean to imply that was wrong .. it's just wrong to wrap *two* `<input>`s.

Comment: OK, the _"only use <label> to wrap text for input"_ had me confused then, glad to clear that up  ;)

Comment: @j08691 The two fields with the same name and id are inside unique conditions.